# Altering label styles (font, color, size, etc.) using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, labeling, idle

I am trying to write a python macro for ArcGIS 10.2 that will automate the process of labeling points in a layer based on different types of apartments.  For example, one style of apartments would have a blue square with white bold text as one label; another would have a pink square with black bold text; another would have a red square with a white bold text, etc.

What expression or function would you use in arcpy to alter the style of these labels?

Currently, the script labels the apartments by a map code and changes its name in the TOC to apartments, as it should.

[image]

Now I want to change the font, graphic, and size of the labels to look make a unique label for each, and then make a button to press and simply automate the process any time we have to do one of these layers.

Is there any way the fonts, labels, and graphics can be changed with the use of Python scripting (ArcPy, IDLE, etc.)?

---

I decided to edit this post to give a final description of what I'm going for here so there's no confusion.  Essentially, the points on the map will go from looking like the above picture to this:

[image]

---

I have tried using the `lblClass.expression` function, however the code I am trying to use doesn't work.  I figure that is probably the step in the right direction. Below is some code that I've tried to use just to get the labelClass.expression to change the fonts of the labels.

```
for lblClass in aptLayer.labelClasses:
lblClass.showClassLabels = True
def getLabel (Code, Type):
if Type == "MRR":
    return "<FNT name = 'Arial' size = '12'>" & Code & "</FNT>"
elif Type == "TAX":
    return "<FNT name = 'Arial' size = '12'>" & Code & "</FNT>"
elif Type == "MRT":
    return "<FNT name = 'Arial' size = '12'>" & Code & "</FNT>"
elif Type == "GSS":
    return "<FNT name = 'Arial' size = '12'>" & Code & "</FNT>"
elif Type == "TGS":
    return "<FNT name = 'Arial' size = '12'>" & Code & "</FNT>"
else:
    return "<FNT name = 'Arial' size = '12'>" & Code & "</FNT>"

lblClass.expression = getLabel( [Map_Code],[Type])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The arcpy.mapping API only provides access to a limited number of
>   layer properties that can be directly modified but all properties
>   found in the Layer Properties dialog box can be modified using the
>   UpdateLayer function. The information is extracted from a source layer
>   and applied to the layer in a map document that needs to be updated.
>   The source_layer can either be a layer (.lyr) file or a layer within a
>   map document. UpdateLayer is a robust function because it can be used
>   in several different ways to produce different results.

You need to create the symbology/labels how you want, and save it to a layer file. Then load that layer file using [arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000003p000000).

If multiple people need to run the python add-in, then you need to make the layer file accessible to everyone, such as a public network drive.

---

I ended up making a custom [Update Layer Properties toolbox](http://ianbroad.com/arcgis-toolbox-using-layer-file-update-layer-properties/). It allows you to select a layer in the ArcMap TOC, and then select an input layer file. It then updates the layer with all the properties within the layer file, and re-sources back to the original feature class. It will work with data that's in gdb, mdb, shp, or sde.

[View the Source Code](http://ianbroad.com/download/script/UpdateLayerProperties.py)

Please let me know if you have any questions.

[image]

Comment: I created a separate layer file from another point based data layer with everything all set (symbology and labels), it executes, but all it seems to do is completely replace the unlabeled, unsymbolized apartment file (whichever one I choose to add) with the sourceLayer apartment file. I'm assuming this is because of the False in the "update symbology only" section. 

Is there a way that this can be executed so it will just apply the symbology and labels but not move the points to a different location?

Comment: What kind of functions would I go about looking for to do that? I'm not too familiar with re-sourcing.  I appreciate your help this far, by the way.

Comment: I tried adjusting this to fit my code. It works up through the UpdateLayer function, but at line 35:
`refocus_layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, original_fc_name)[0]` it throws an error saying that the index is out of range.

Comment: That means that the `arcpy.mapping.ListLayers` method is not finding a layer in the current mxd with the same name as your `input_layer_file` (an index of `[0]` returning index out of range means there are no items in the list).

Comment: I did, and I feel like this is very close, but the problem is, after the UpdateLayer part finishes, it throws the following error: 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\_Tyler Temp\Python\IanTest.py", line 30, in <module>
    refocus_layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, original_fc_name)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Perhaps I have the parameters wrong? the file that's being updated is in .shp form, and the file that the symbology and label properties is being exported from is in .lyr form.

Comment: @ian I just did. It goes through all the way up to where it completes the UpdateLayer() function and then throws the same error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\_Tyler Temp\Python\UpdateLayerProperties.tbx#UpdateLayerProperties_UpdateLayerProperties.py", line 40, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range`  I added the layer to the mxd and set that as the parameter, and I set the .lyr file to the layer that has the symbology and label properties I want to get.  It's like it doesn't put the new layer at the beginning of its "list".

Comment: @TylerSpears Whooops, same for me! I made a mistake, I used the dataSetName instead of just name for the original_fc_name. I updated the script above, and put a new toolbox out, will you download it and try again? http://www.ianbroad.com/download/toolbox/UpdateLayerProperties.tbx Thanks.

Comment: @ian I just tried that one and got the same error. `File "E:\_Tyler Temp\Python\UpdateLayerProperties.tbx#UpdateLayerProperties_UpdateLayerProperties.py", line 40, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range`. Is there maybe a module that should be imported in the code other than ArcPy?

Comment: @TylerSpears did you completely close out of ArcMap and then add the new toolbox? Sometimes it keeps the old one in memory. Delete the old one, and download the new one- make sure you aren't accidentally using the old one.

Comment: @ian Nailed it! Thank you very much. So just so I understand what's going on here, the tool finds the input layer's data source, and then performs the UpdateLayer function to replace the input layer with the source layer, in all properties, and then goes back and replaces the source layer's data with the input layer's data?

Comment: @TylerSpears Awesome! Here's some quick comments, hopefully they make sense. Let me know if there are any other questions: http://pastebin.com/QjL5YusT But, yes, what you said is what's happening.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to set custom label expression on the layer (changing size and color..etc) using python:

e.g.

```
def FindLabel ( [NAME], [POPULATION] ):
  if long([POPULATION]) >= 250000:
    return "<CLR red='255'><FNT size = '14'>" + [NAME] + "</FNT></CLR>"
  else:
    return [NAME]
```

[Building label expressions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s800000027000000)

They may be set via:

[LabelClass (arcpy.mapping)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s30000002t000000)

**EDIT:**

Try this:

```
def FindLabel ([Code], [Type]):
  if [Type] == "MRR":
    return "<FNT name = 'Arial' size = '12'>" + Code + "</FNT>"
  elif [Type] == "TAX":
    return "<FNT name = 'Arial' size = '12'>" + Code + "</FNT>"
  elif [Type] == "MRT":
    return "<FNT name = 'Arial' size = '12'>" + Code + "</FNT>"
  elif [Type] == "GSS":
    return "<FNT name = 'Arial' size = '12'>" + Code + "</FNT>"
  elif [Type] == "TGS":
    return "<FNT name = 'Arial' size = '12'>" + Code + "</FNT>"
  else:
    return "<FNT name = 'Arial' size = '12'>" + Code + "</FNT>"
```

You can remove your other line statements (for loop, labClass, and call to function).  Also, the function needs to be called FindLabel.

Comment: I tried to utilize something similar to a function like this. I created a definition called `def getLabel (Code, Type)` and then after setting up the if-else statements for the different map codes I use, I then set 'lblClass.expression = getLabel( "[Map_Code]","[Type]" )', which just returns an error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'` I'm basically following the Esri website's examples. If I can simply prove I can change the font, I can then move on to adjusting the more difficult aspects (such as the shape, background and color of the labels).

Comment: @Tyler Spears, Try removing the double quotes around the field names.

Comment: When I do that, it says that the parameters aren't defined.

Comment: @Tyler Spears, Can you post your code in your question?  You have a single quote outside of the function parentheses.

Comment: Absolutely, I have updated my question to show my code.